# Telegram-бот от имени юзера

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Все мы знаем как создавать Telegram-бота, чтобы он писал от имени самого себя.

В данном случае меня интересует возможность прикрутить бота к своему аккаунту в телеграму. Возможно ли это вообще сделать? Если да - скиньте ссылки на статьи, где можно почитать как это сделать или опишите шаги по настройке данной вещи.

*Если у вас есть вопросы - пишите о них в комментариях. На вопросы "для чего это мне?" я не даю ответа.*

Comment: Не возможно. Разве что писать бота уже вокруг веб версии телеграма и отсылать сообщения там, от своего имени

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko понял. А есть где-то пруф этому? Если да, то можешь добавить ссылку на источник и кинуть свой коммент в ответы)

Comment: Не знаю какой пруф достать) Знаю что они ботов создавали изначально с расчетом, чтобы из них спам ботов не делали.